# Communication b/w Angular Components: Using @Input, @Output and Sharedservice. Which one to use?

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]Scenario:

Clicking on a node on Tree displays the contained data on right.
In my case the node is a Folder and the data is the contained Devices in folder.
The node component and the data showing component are siblings.

Implementation:

1. If we use @Input and @Output we could do this by creating a chain between 6 components.
2. Otherwise we could create a shared service using subject it could be used in any component using subscribe. This has an advnatage of avoiding the chain of connections.

I am not sure how to go about this with the normal @Input @Output or a shared service.

If someone could point out advantages and disadvantages or how to go about this, it would be really helpful.

Comment: sounds like a shared service is the way to go here?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a service for fetching the data when it's not directly coming from the parent/child-component.

Your project will become confusing if you keep on using a pattern like this, passing objects to parts of the program that do not need it.
I would also consider it a massive anti-pattern, because not only will you pass unnecessary data through several components, you would also have to modify all your components at once if - for example - you happen to change the name of the object being passed around. Which only means extra work and more susceptibility to errors.

By not using the service-implemenation you would also violate a fundamental design principle of Computer Science called "[Seperation of Concerns](https://deviq.com/separation-of-concerns/)" (which basically means 'do one thing and do it well'), since only 2 of your 6 components actually need the data that's being passed around.

Also, should another one of your components also start requiring the data, you would have to create another 'chain', possibly spanning several more components that have no need for the data. With a service, you can simply inject it and request the data when needed.

Comment: the components to communicate are siblings. then also should i use service?